# Execution error when trying to run pyflink Word_count.py in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I've been experimenting with the pyflink api recently, I wanted to execute the given example of word_count in the datastream directory, but I ended up with the following error

python3 examples/python/datastream/word_count.py

```
sing Any for unsupported type: typing.Sequence[~T]
No module named google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1. As a result, the ReadFromBigQuery transform *CANNOT* be used with `method=DIRECT_READ`.
Executing word_count example with default input data set.
Use --input to specify file input.
Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sarannathreddy/Downloads/flink-1.18.1/examples/python/datastream/word_count.py", line 134, in <module>
    word_count(known_args.input, known_args.output)
  File "/Users/sarannathreddy/Downloads/flink-1.18.1/examples/python/datastream/word_count.py", line 113, in word_count
    env.execute()
  File "/Users/sarannathreddy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyflink/datastream/stream_execution_environment.py", line 773, in execute
    return JobExecutionResult(self._j_stream_execution_environment.execute(j_stream_graph))
  File "/Users/sarannathreddy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/sarannathreddy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/sarannathreddy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o12.execute.
: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2079)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(PekkoInvocationHandler.java:268)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2079)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1267)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2079)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ScalaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(ScalaFutureUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:310)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:307)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:234)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ScalaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(ScalaFutureUtils.java:65)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288)
    at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:629)
    at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:34)
    at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:536)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:73)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:59)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$PekkoForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:176)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:285)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:276)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:269)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:764)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:741)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:488)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(PekkoRpcActor.java:309)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(PekkoRpcActor.java:307)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.FencedPekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedPekkoRpcActor.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:168)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:33)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:545)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:229)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.apache.flink.python.util.PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.execute(PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.java:176)
    at org.apache.flink.python.util.PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.getPythonUdfRunnerScript(PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.python.env.process.ProcessPythonEnvironmentManager.createEnvironment(ProcessPythonEnvironmentManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createPythonExecutionEnvironment(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:441)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.lambda$open$0(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:269)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.lambda$getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory$5(MemoryManager.java:539)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.createResource(SharedResources.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.getOrAllocateSharedResource(SharedResources.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory(MemoryManager.java:555)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:272)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.java:57)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.ExternalPythonProcessOperator.open(ExternalPythonProcessOperator.java:64)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:753)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:728)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:693)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:953)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:922)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:746)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 25 more
```

I am currently working on an m2 macbook air, with python 3.9.6 as the interpreter, flink is version 1.18.1

I was expecting for the file to run without any errors, but the same error keeps popping up. I want to resolve this as I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by this line in the output

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

it looks like Flink is looking for "python" rather than "python3". You should be able to work around this by creating a link from "python" to "python3", or something to that effect.